# GUIのコンポーネントを自作したい

Tags: wpf, electron, gui

現在、AviUtl (動画編集ソフト) のようなタイムラインを持った、GUIで動くソフトを作ろうとしています。しかしタイムラインのような用途が限られるUIコンポーネントはなかなか既存ではなく、自作しようと思っています。

タイムラインに限らず、自分で任意のUIが欲しくなったときに自作できるようにしたいのですが、どのようにしたら作ることができるでしょうか？

選択肢は Electron、WPF、Windows Form あたりです。
書ける言語は Python, C++, C#, Typescript あたりです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

UIコンポーネントとして独立した部品を作りたいのか、特殊なUIを持ったアプリケーションを作りたいのかで若干方向性が違いますが、C#(.NET Framework)を使って既存にないUIを作ることができます。

まずは部品から、とお考えであれば、検索ワード「カスタムコントロール」で調べてみると結構事例が見つかると思います。ただ、これで見つかるのは開発方法であって、今考えておられる機能を実現するには、それなりにWindowsシステムや.NET Frameworkに精通する必要があると思います。先は長いかもしれませんが頑張ってください。